# How do I stack two elements differently in mobile vs desktop?

Tags: css

I have two elements wrapped in a narrow bootstrap col3 column. I want it to display 1 and 2 in order on desktop. Then 2 and 1 in mobile. Floating doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the demo code:

```css
.custom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .custom {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row custom">
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <span>
        Box 1, class is just for demonstration
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <span>
        Box 2, class is just for demonstration
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuong's answer is great for this particular scenario, but for cases where more than two elements exist in the container in question, CSS Flexbox provides an order property that can be used to change the order of HTML elements contained in a flexbox (or even a CSS grid). Here's an example:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #BADA55;
  margin: 1rem;
}

@media(max-width: 520px) {
  .second {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="foo first">1</div>
  <div class="foo second">2</div>
  <div class="foo third">3</div>
</div>
```

For more information, refer to the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).